# Control mouse with keyboard in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cursor, keyboard-navigation, mouseless

I'm looking for a program that I can use to control the mouse from the keyboard.
I think a video can explain it much better than I could, so please check out Mouser from lifehacker.com:

http://lifehacker.com/212816/hack-attack-operate-your-mouse-with-your-keyboard

Unfortunately, it's only for Windows, but something like this would be the perfect solution.
I found a lot of help on mapping keys to programs, but nothing about mapping keys to mouse control.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at that HackaDay article, it says he created Mouser.exe after viewing a presentation from a guy at Google. Google's known for its use of linux, right? One of the links from your HackaDay article took me here: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/keynav/
And here is a demo of [keynav in action](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/keynav/keynav.html)

Just tested on Ubuntu 10.10 and it works fine. I had to install libxdo-dev before it would build (make), but then it ran fine. Note there's no 'make install' target, so just copy the keynav binary it builds to someplace in your path (~/bin, /opt/bin, etc).

Doesn't work awesome with dual monitors.**Edit:** NM. Split at least once, than use Shift+[hjkl] to move the divider around. That can jump you to the other screen.

Comment: keynav is great, I've been using it for years. I'd also like to point out [warpd](https://github.com/rvaiya/warpd), which has a few more features. It's currently only packaged for Arch, though, which is why I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 7):

It can help out partially . `System` -> `Settings` -> `Assistive Technologies`; then `Keyboard Accessibility`, under "`Mouse Buttons`"

Also using [Shortcuts](http://www.saylinux.com/LinuxKeyboardShortcuts.htm) may help you too.

another way is using `ctrl-shift-numlock` that is supposed to be the key combo that will let you move the cursor with the keyboard. But, I can't very sure that it works, since my laptop doesn't have a dedicated numlock key. you can control the mouse from keyboard. Keys / and * on the numpad select left mouse click and right mouse click respectively. Mouse click is done by 5 on the numpad.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 11, Gnome I found this in `System` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard` and then `Mouse Keys` tab and check `Pointer can be controlled using keypad`.

To access System menu use `ALT`+`F1` shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu users you can try:

1. `System-settings`
2. `Universal Access`
3. `Pointing and Clicking` tab
4. Switch off the key that says `Mouse keys`.

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to control the mouse from the keyboard, but with a different set of actions for keys.  I implemented this functionality with a little utility program that I've put up on GitHub:

https://github.com/SalmonChris/KeyboardMouse

Comment: Neat, thank you for sharing!  that's a really clever solution, and I much appreciate the flexibility of the code

Comment: Nice little program :)

Comment: Would it be more convenient to use a special key to toggle into mouse mode and then use arrow keys, etc, to control the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

You may also check `mouseless`

https://github.com/jbensmann/mouseless

> It works in all Linux distributions, even those running with Wayland.
>
> It is the successor of xmouseless, which depended on X11 and had some minor issues.

Features:

- move the pointer continuously
- change the pointer speed on the fly
- click, grab, scroll
- remap keys
- define arbitrary layers

plus

- execute arbitrary commands

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 23.10 ships with this feature by default. Open *Settings*, navigate to *Accessibility*, then *Pointing and Clicking*, and enable *Mouse Keys*.

[image: Screenshot that says: Mouse Keys: Use numeric keypad to move your mouse pointer]