# Ubuntu: On-screen keyboard without typing

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

On a similar note to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/122142/control-mouse-with-keyboard-in-ubuntu), I recently booted Ubuntu to recover a Windows partition, but couldn't in any way get the keyboard to register.

I recall back in 8.x that you could easily reach the on-screen keyboard (Virtual Keyboard?) via "Assistive Technologies". It seems to have disappeared since 9.x.

For future reference, how can I easily get to it? Recall that in this scenario I won't have a keyboard to enter terminal commands (e.g. to install `xkbd` or something of the like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get an on-screen keyboard working, is by using a keyboard. Granted, [it is easy to do](http://www.combibo.net/articles/using_an_onscreen_keyboard_in_ubuntu/) — all you need to do is install `onboard` — but it is *not* possible to use Ubuntu without a keyboard.

I would be delighted to be corrected, and will accept any answer that gets an on-screen keyboard up using only the mouse.

Comment: see my answer! ;). selecting character and use copy/paste option from right click menu.

Answer (score 3):

[xvkbd](http://homepage3.nifty.com/tsato/xvkbd/) is a small on screen keyboard that is just fantastic.

[image]

**UPDATE**: for installation:

1. untar [the source](http://homepage3.nifty.com/tsato/xvkbd/#download) in a directory, and move to the directory
2. If you wish to use genuine Xaw insead of Xaw3d, edit Imakefile and remove (or comment-out) #define XAW3D.

   When you are installing xvkbd (for example) in very old systems, you may also want to remove #define XTEST and #define I18N to disable XTEST and internationalization facility respectively.
3. Run `xmkmf; make install install.man`

Comment: And how do I install it?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: The only way of doing this is really to use the mouse to copy/paste the terminal commands from above.

Comment: There's no way I could possibly get this to work. First of all, I can't log in, because I can't type my password. Even if I installed Ubuntu without a password, I wouldn't be able to find this page, because I can't type in the URL. In the end I grabbed a different keyboard that did register in Ubuntu, but that doesn't address the OP.

Answer (score 0):

you can! Look at this screen capture I did :

https://disk.yandex.ru/d/mpOslBTPfPrO2Q

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are in emergency and have only a mouse! right click on desktop, select open terminal here! when terminal opens, it writes some lines, for example:
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), ... 
to write commands select each character in the above line and copy/paste it in the command line! 
if you didn't find the required character, go and find the character in a file name! for example if you need character 'x' find it in name of some file and right click on file name and choose rename, then select the 'x' character, copy it and then paste it in the terminal, for 'Enter' select entire line and copy / paste it after your command.
[image: right click on character]